# Css :Hover::before conflict with mouseenter in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, carousel

I am trying to make a carousel that you hover on a small image it will be shown in large size. I ran into some problem with my css hover::before. It makes the jQuery sometimes work sometimes it does not. Can someone have a solution?
I have my own solution but it has compalibility issue with IE9

Note: I don't know why the code snipet doesn't render the boostrap link. It's a bit messy in the outcome. Please ignore that, thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.menu').find('img').mouseenter(function(){
        const display = $('#large-img').find('img') /*large img */
        const source = $(this).attr('src')          /*source of menu img*/

        if (source != display.attr('src'))          /*dont fade out when large img and menu img are the same */
            display.fadeOut(100,function(){
            $('#large-img').children().css('display','block').attr('src',`${source}`)
        })
    })
})
```

```css
.menu div{
            position: relative;
        }
        .menu div:hover::before{
            position: absolute;
            content: "";
            top: 6px;
            bottom: 6px;
            left: 6px;
            right: 6px;
            border: 3px solid tomato;
        }
        /* .menu img:hover{
            outline: 3px solid tomato;        <!-My solution-->
            outline-offset: -3px;
        } */
```

```html
<body>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 py-5">
                        <div id="large-img">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/700x450" alt="">               
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <div class="p-2">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/700x450" width="100px" height="50px" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="p-2">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/701x450" width="100px" height="50px" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="p-2">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/702x450" width="100px" height="50px" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="p-2">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/703x450" width="100px" height="50px" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="p-2">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/704x450" width="100px" height="50px" alt="">
                            </div>
                      </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha512-WNLxfP/8cVYL9sj8Jnp6et0BkubLP31jhTG9vhL/F5uEZmg5wEzKoXp1kJslzPQWwPT1eyMiSxlKCgzHLOTOTQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: The ***final*** version of IE9 was released in 2011. Welcome to 2020.

Comment: I'm looking for why they don't work well with each other. I'm not pretty sure about what the "::before" does that prevent the jQuery. If there is a solution for that approach i would 
have a better understand of what they do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know jQuery Migrate? Try it if it will help you. If not, forget for IE9. Market share of IE9 is approx. 1.2%?
https://www.stetic.com/market-share/browser/

You spend time for approx. 1% users and lose time for rest of 99% users.